# Adding entry in SAS based on column value

Tags: sql, sas

I'm attempting to add an additional entry to a SAS data set if there is no entry of value 1 in column 'Count' for a specific subject and their respective test. The entry would have the 'Test' column value added, as well as 'Missing' for column 'Value' and 1 for Count.

Here is the data:

```
Subject            Test               Value                 Count
001                Test1              Normal                0
001                Test2              Normal                0
001                Test2              High                  1
002                Test1              Normal                0
002                Test2              Normal                0
002                Test2              Normal                1
```

I would like to create the following data set:

```
Subject            Test               Value                 Count
001                Test1              Normal                0
001                Test1              Missing               1
001                Test2              Normal                0
001                Test2              High                  1
002                Test1              Normal                0
002                Test1              Missing               1
002                Test2              Normal                0
002                Test2              Normal                1
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `retain` and `first`, `last`:

```
proc sort data=have; /*sort data to use first. and last.*/
by Subject Test;
run;

data want(drop=check_count);
   set have;
   By Subject Test;
   retain check_count;/*in this variable we will store 1 - if there is count that equals to 1 in subject and test group, and 0 - if there is no  count that equals to 1 in subject and test group*/
   if first.test then check_count=0; /*init variable for new test group*/
   if count = 1 then check_count = 1; /*change value when there is count = 1*/
   output;
   if last.test and check_count=0 then do;
      Value="Missing";
      Count=1;
      output;
   end;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just use `union all`:

```
proc sql;
    select subject, test, value, count
    from data d
    union all
    select subject, test, 'Missing', 1
    from data d
    group by subject, test
    having max(count) = 0;
```